# SummerNote Text Edit button images not loaded

Tags: summernote

I want to put Summer Note Wysiwyg editor to my HTML. Everything works fine, but the button-images are not loaded correctly. I am adding screenshot.

[image: screenshot of the behaviour]
Any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

you must include fonawesome

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```